# Looking for a reporting solution that plays nicely with MVC3 and SQL Azure. Any suggestions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, reporting, reportviewer, solution

I've been doing some researching and I've found that the ReportViewer control we'll have to use with Azure-based SSRS doesn't play nicely with MVC3.  Can anyone recommend a reporting solution that integrates nicely with Azure and MVC3?

Answer (score 1):

You can still host ASP.NET controls within MVC sites.  Check out this link for more information on how to integrate ReportViewer ASP.NET control into an MVC site:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-i.aspx

Alternatively, there is an open-source project around a custom-built MVC-compatible RDLC control.  I have not used it and know little about it, but if you want to check it out: http://mvcrdlc.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, lgorek.  I'm also investigating this product right now:  http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Reports-Web.aspx